# Opening a new tab and trying to scroll down the page and clicking on a link fails in Firefox browser

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have this function where I am trying to scroll down the page and click on a link. I have put the code in a for loop because I want to open more than one tab. 
The links which I am trying to click are out of view of the window and they are in footer which is common for all the web pages. My method is supposed to scroll down till the link to be clicked is visible and then control + click and open a new tab. The method works perfectly well in Chrome and Internet Explorer browsers but fails in Firefox saying that the link to be clicked is not present. I think it is not scrolling down despite my putting code to scroll down. Please help.

```
public static void checkHrefsWithBrowserUrls(List<WebElement> links) 
{
 String parentTab = null;
 String clickOnLink = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);

 log.debug("Checking that the links open the correct url");
 for (WebElement link : links) {
     ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
        .executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", link);
     String href = link.getAttribute("href");
     link.sendKeys(clickOnLink);
     WaitUtilities.sleep(1L);
     Iterator<String> handleIterator = driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();

     parentTab = handleIterator.next();

     if(handleIterator.hasNext()) {
         driver.switchTo().window(handleIterator.next());
         WaitUtilities.waitForUrlToBe(url());
         if(!href.equals(url())) {
             log.error("Link(s) opening wrong URL(s): " + url());
         }
         driver.close();
         driver.switchTo().window(parentTab);
     }
 }
 driver.switchTo().window(parentTab);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the link without scrolling? you can use javascript click, you don't have to scroll to the element.

Comment: .click should scroll automatically, so no need to scroll.  I think the problem you are seeing here has to do with the way different browsers order tabs.  You can't rely on the array of window handles to be ordered in any specific way.  (I think some browsers "add" and some "push".)  So you are assuming the next item in the array is the next tab, and that won't always be true across browsers.  You want to keep track of the handles themselves since they will be unique.

Comment: @Supputuri: I am getting the following exception                 org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference of <a href="my url"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html.                              I am not sure, but I think the the parent window is getting refreshed and that could be the reason I am facing this issue.

Comment: @pcalkins: After opening each tab, i am finishing the task i need to do and closing the tab before i attempt to open a new tab.

Comment: You are right, link does not work from links as it will loose the reference once you click on the first link. Make sure to pass the locator rather elements list, and get the elements and use the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pseudo code to handle the state element issue.

```
public static void checkHrefsWithBrowserUrls(String xpath) 
{
     String parentTab = null;
     String clickOnLink = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);

     log.debug("Checking that the links open the correct url");
     int linksCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).size();
     for (int linkCounter=1; linkCounter=linksCount, linkCounter++) {
         link = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).get(linkCounter)
         ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
            .executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", link);
         String href = link.getAttribute("href");
         link.sendKeys(clickOnLink);
         WaitUtilities.sleep(1L);
         Iterator<String> handleIterator = driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();

         parentTab = handleIterator.next();

         if(handleIterator.hasNext()) {
             driver.switchTo().window(handleIterator.next());
             WaitUtilities.waitForUrlToBe(url());
             if(!href.equals(url())) {
                 log.error("Link(s) opening wrong URL(s): " + url());
          }
          driver.close();
     driver.switchTo().window(parentTab);
    }
   }
   driver.switchTo().window(parentTab);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. It works and my issue is resolved.